# Multiple upload codeigniter cannot validate the upload path

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have the controller code for multiple upload file like this:

```
public function submit_add() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $article = new Article_mdl();
        $article->artikel_title = $this->input->post('artikel_title');
        $article->artikel_date = $this->input->post('artikel_date');
        $article->artikel_text = $this->input->post('artikel_text');
        $article->arkat_id = $this->input->post('arkat_id');
        if (!empty($_FILES['artikel_image']['name'])) {

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('artikel_image')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error);
                exit();
            } else {
                $article->user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                $article->artikel_is_active = 1;
                $idartikel = $article->insert();

                $files = $_FILES;
                $cpt = count($_FILES['artikel_image']['name']);
                $dataPhoto = array();
                for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){

                    $_FILES['artikel_image']['name']= $files['artikel_image']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['artikel_image']['type']= $files['artikel_image']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['artikel_image']['tmp_name']= $files['artikel_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['artikel_image']['error']= $files['artikel_image']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['artikel_image']['size']= $files['artikel_image']['size'][$i];    

                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                $this->upload->do_upload();
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($xxx);die;
                $dataPhoto[] = array('artikel_photo_artikel_id' => $idartikel, 'artikel_photo_images' => $_FILES['artikel_image']['name'], 'artikel_photo_status' => 1);
            }
            $article->insertArtikelPhoto($dataPhoto);

            }
        }

        redirect('admin/article/');
    }

private function set_upload_options(){   
    //  upload an image options
        $config = array();

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/article/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '0';
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;

        return $config;
    }
```

My question why when i submit the data i got the error **"The upload path does not appear to be valid."** the folder path config is exist. what the wrong?
please help...Thank's before for help and I'll appreciate  :)

Answer (score 0):

Because server hasn't directory uploads

Comment: the realpath = /var/www/codeigniter/kpudbdg/upload/article             base URL http://localhost/codeigniter/kpudbdg/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `site_url()` or `base_url()` to make sure your path is correct.
2. And set the folder permission to  `777 or rwxrwxrwx`
3. Change `max_size` to some other value than zero.
4. modify to `$config['upload_path'] = './upload/article';`

Comment: still get error **"The upload path does not appear to be valid."**